# check my solution to indefinite integral problem with arccos

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

So we had homework it asked us to find $$\int\arccos(x)dx$$

I have found that $$\int\arccos(x)dx=x\arccos (x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}+c$$

Is this right?

Comment: If I may give you a small trick : when you have computed the antiderivative, just differentiate the result : it must be identical to the integrand. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate by parts:
$$\int \arccos xdx= x\arccos x+\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=x\arccos x-\sqrt{1-x^2}+C$$

Comment: Well, it is $x\arccos x$ and not $\arccos x$ alone. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع

Comment: You're welcome @Sami!

Answer (score 1):

It is *approximately* right since it should be:

$$\int \arccos(x)\,\mathrm dx=x\arccos(x)\color{red}{\mathbf{-}}\sqrt{1-x^2}+\text{const.}$$

Be careful next time when dealing with minuses and pluses. ;-)

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Comment: ill do next time... thanks...

Comment: @user140637 You're welcome! Glad it helps. $ \overset{                                                                       \cdot                                                                \cdot                            }                                 \smile$